# I need to display the selected date in header in fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Is there any way way by which the selected date can be display on the header as user clicks on date in fullcalendar angular.

```
   headerToolbar: {
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev title next'
    },
```

As mentioned in the above short code on the centre of header toolbar instead of title i nedd to display the date selected by the user as user clicks on the dates dynamically.

Comment: "Is there any way way by which the selected date can be display on the header"...not easily, not, without amending the raw HTML directly (outside of any of fullCalendar's APIs). Consider displaying it somewhere else on your page. The selected area gets highlighted in the calendar area anyway though, so it should already be quite obvious to the user what they have selected. Also bear in mind that a user may not select a single date necessarily - they may select a time range of multiple days, or just a few hours, or some combination of those.

Comment: ok thanks for  the help @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson is there any way by which on selecting a date the background of cell and color to date can be changed?

Comment: If you're using the `select` callback functionality of fullCalendar then that should happen automatically, it will highlight the selected area in a different colour

Comment: @ADyson yeah the selected are color is different but I also need to change color the date font .Is there any way to do this, with css i have tried but when using it the font color of all dates get changed , but i need to only change the font color of selected date.

Comment: "I also need to change color the date font"...do you though, _really_? What if the user selects half a day? Or two and half days? Will you change all those days, or only the full ones? I guess you could do it, but it's probably fiddly code - especially as that code would probably need to be different for each view type you're enabling in your calendar - and I'd question whether it's really worth it. Does it really affect the UX all that much? Everyone else seems to manage without it in their calendar.

Comment: If you look at the element inspector in your browser, when a calendar is loaded, you can see that in the month view, dates are in a td such as this: `<td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2021-01-06"><span class="fc-day-number">6</span></td>`. So you could use the data-date attribute to target the specific date(s) you need, I guess. Structure is similar for the timeGrid views, but I haven't checked the others, maybe you can take a look. So yeah it could be made to work if you really want, I guess.

Comment: The change of font color is for the purpose of interactive calendar when the user click on a date cell the highlight should occur and with the the date font color should also change even if he selects multiple dates both cells should display a highlighted background color with changed date color. @ADyson

Comment: Ok. Well if got really want to do it I've just given you the suggestion how it might be done